# Bounds for expectation of exchangeable random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, inequality

I am stuck with the following problem from research.

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d standard normal gaussian. 
Let M be the set of exchangeable random variables $\{X_1 - X_t; t\ne 1\}$.

I am trying to derive an upper bound for the $\mathrm{E}\{e^{{\text{Max } M}}\}$.

Any hints on how to proceed ?

Comment: What is the correspondence between the set $M$ and the random variable $M_t$? Is $M=\{M_t\colon t\neq 1\}$?

Comment: @HowDoIMath Sorry. Edited the question.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167528/bounds-for-expectation-of-exchangeable-random-variables. The minimum is negative this (by symmetry). So this gives you a bound the minimum of $X_t$.

Comment: @DaleM Is the above link correct? I keep coming back to the same page.